# Keylogger with accurate timestamps for Linux

Tags: linux, statistics, keylogger

I'm curious about my typing, what combinations of letters or modifiers usually take me the most time, etc.

For that, I'm searching for a program that logs the keys I press, each with a time stamp, and ideally exports the data in a friendly format. So far,  failing to find one.

If that's not possible, at least a program that records statistics on time taken for combinations of 2 or 3 key presses, or something of the sort.
The time stamps need to have higher granularity than "seconds" to be useful.